# Remover objeto de um array e de uma tabela - JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Estou criando um sistema de cadastro epidemiológico. Uma das funções consiste em remover um objeto já cadastrado do sistema. Quando o objeto é cadastrado, ele é adicionado a um array e também a uma tabela que exibe todos os registros.
Preciso criar uma função que remova esse objeto tanto do array quanto da tabela.
Tentei criar essa função, mas ela não funciona corretamente.
Vou mostrar todo o sistema:

```js
let vetorPessoa = [];

function cadastro() {
  function checagemCampos() {
    if (document.getElementById('cep').value === "") {
      alert("Preencha o campo CEP corretamente!");
      document.getElementById('cep').focus();
    } else if (document.getElementById('populacao').value === "") {
      alert("Preencha o campo POPULAÇÃO corretamente!");
      document.getElementById('populacao').focus();
    } else {
      function insereLinha() {
        let objetoPessoa = {};

        let inputCEP = document.getElementById("cep");
        let inputRaio = document.getElementById("raio");
        let inputPop = document.getElementById("populacao");
        let inputCarac = document.getElementById("caracteristica");

        objetoPessoa.cep = inputCEP.value;
        objetoPessoa.raio = inputRaio.value;
        objetoPessoa.pop = inputPop.value;
        objetoPessoa.caracteristica = inputCarac.value;

        vetorPessoa.push(objetoPessoa);

        let novaLinha = document.createElement("tr");

        let tdCEP = document.createElement("td");
        let txtCEP = document.createTextNode(inputCEP.value)
        tdCEP.appendChild(txtCEP);

        let tdRaio = document.createElement("td");
        let txtRaio = document.createTextNode(inputRaio.value);
        tdRaio.appendChild(txtRaio);

        let tdPop = document.createElement("td");
        let txtPop = document.createTextNode(inputPop.value);
        tdPop.appendChild(txtPop);

        let tdCarac = document.createElement("td");
        let txtCarac = document.createTextNode(inputCarac.value);
        tdCarac.appendChild(txtCarac);

        novaLinha.appendChild(tdCEP);
        novaLinha.appendChild(tdRaio);
        novaLinha.appendChild(tdPop);
        novaLinha.appendChild(tdCarac);

        let cTabela = document.getElementById("corpoTabela");
        cTabela.appendChild(novaLinha);

        function limpaForm() {
          document.getElementById('formulario').reset();
        }
        limpaForm();
      }
      insereLinha();
      // S
    }

  }
  checagemCampos();
}

function remover() {
  let inputCEP = document.getElementById("cep");
  let buscar = inputCEP.value;
  let indice = vetorPessoa.indexOf(buscar);
  while (indice >= 0) {
    vetorPessoa.slice(indice, 1);
    indice = vetorPessoa.indexOf(buscar);
  }
  console.log(vetorPessoa);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Controle de Epidemias</title>

  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Nunito:wght@300;400;600;700;800&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css">
  <link rel="script" href="assets/js/script.js">
</head>

<body>

  <div id="app">
    <div id="sidebar" class="active">
      <div class="sidebar-wrapper active">
        <div class="sidebar-header">
          <div class="logo">
            <a href="locais.html"><img src="assets/images/logo/logo01.png" alt=""></a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="sidebar-menu">
          <ul class="mainmenu">
            <li>
              <a href="locais.html">
                <span>Cadastro de Locais</span>
              </a>
              <ul class="submenu">
                <li><a>Listar todos</a></li>
                <li><a>Listar um</a></li>
                <li><a>Incluir</a></li>
                <li><a>Alterar</a></li>
                <li><a>Excluir</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>

            <li class="sidebar-item">
              <a href="pragas.html">
                <span>Cadastro de Pragas</span>
              </a>
              <ul class="submenu">
                <li><a>Listar todos</a></li>
                <li><a>Listar um</a></li>
                <li><a>Incluir</a></li>
                <li><a>Alterar</a></li>
                <li><a>Excluir</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>

            <li class="sidebar-item">
              <a href="contaminacoes.html">
                <span>Contaminacoes</span>
              </a>
              <ul class="submenu">
                <li><a>Listar todos</a></li>
                <li><a>Listar um</a></li>
                <li><a>Incluir</a></li>
                <li><a>Alterar</a></li>
                <li><a>Excluir</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>

            <li class="sidebar-item  ">
              <a href="relatorios.html">
                <span>Relatórios</span>
              </a>
              <ul class="submenu">
                <li><a>Listar todos</a></li>
                <li><a>Listar um</a></li>
                <li><a>Incluir</a></li>
                <li><a>Alterar</a></li>
                <li><a>Excluir</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>

            <li class="sidebar-item  ">
              <a href="sair.html">
                <span>Sair</span>
              </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
    <section class="contact-form">
      <h1>Cadastro de Locais</h1>
      <form id="formulario">
        <div class="input-group">
          <label for="cep">CEP:</label>
          <input id="cep" name="cep" type="text" placeholder="00.000-000" />
        </div>

        <div class="input-group">
          <label for="raio">Raio: </label>
          <input id="raio" name="raio" type="text" placeholder="50 (em km)" />
        </div>

        <div class="input-group">
          <label for="populacao">População: </label>
          <input id="populacao" name="populacao" type="text" placeholder="10.000" />
        </div>

        <div class="input-group">
          <label for="caracteristica">Características: </label>
          <input id="caracteristica" name="caracteristica" type="text" placeholder="Matas, lixo" />
        </div>

        <button type="button" onclick="cadastro()">Cadastrar</button>
        <button type="button" onclick="remover()">Remover</button>
      </form>
    </section>

    <div class="resultado">
      <h1 style="text-align: center">Cadastros</h1>
      <table class="tg">
        <thead>
          <th>CEP</th>
          <th>Raio</th>
          <th>Poulação</th>
          <th>Características</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="corpoTabela">
          <tr>

          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
    <footer id="rodape">
      <p>All rights reserved &copy - 2021</p>
    </footer>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: BiancaBorges02, não entendi muito bem é para remover o cadastro pelo CEP?

Comment: Isso, Augusto. Quando eu realizo o cadastro, tudo vai para dentro do vetorPessoa. Quando eu excluo o cadastro, ele é deletado do vetorPessoa, mas não é deletado da tabela que o exibe.

Answer (score 0):

- A `function remover()` apresentou alguns problemas na execução por conta do **escopo** das variáveis e pelo uso do **DOM**. Além disso, não ficou muito claro como você quer utilizar esta função, segundo a estrutura do seu site ela deveria apagar todos os elementos do *array* e da tabela.
- Importante lembrar que as variáveis declaradas dentro de uma `function` possuem escopo **local** e só podem ser acessadas por outra `function` por meio da passagem de parâmetros por valor ou referência.
- Um sugestão simples seria você declarar algumas variáveis fora das functions, para atribuir um escopo **global** e utilizar os métodos `.hasChildNodes()` e `.removeChild(cTabela.childNodes[0])` para remover os elementos **child** da tabela.
- Exemplo:

```
let vetorPessoa = []
let cTabela = document.getElementById("corpoTabela")
let inputCEP = document.getElementById("cep")
let inputRaio = document.getElementById("raio")
let inputPop = document.getElementById("populacao")
let inputCarac = document.getElementById("caracteristica")
    
function cadastro() {
    function checagemCampos() {
        if (inputCEP.value === "") {
        alert("Preencha o campo CEP corretamente!")
        inputCEP.focus()

        } else if (inputPop.value === "") {
            alert("Preencha o campo POPULAÇÃO corretamente!")
            inputPop.focus()

        } else {
            function insereLinha() {
                let objetoPessoa = {}
    
                objetoPessoa.cep = inputCEP.value
                objetoPessoa.raio = inputRaio.value
                objetoPessoa.pop = inputPop.value
                objetoPessoa.caracteristica = inputCarac.value
    
                vetorPessoa.push(objetoPessoa)
                let novaLinha = document.createElement("tr")
    
                let tdCEP = document.createElement("td")
                let txtCEP = document.createTextNode(inputCEP.value)
                tdCEP.appendChild(txtCEP)
    
                let tdRaio = document.createElement("td")
                let txtRaio = document.createTextNode(inputRaio.value)
                tdRaio.appendChild(txtRaio)
    
                let tdPop = document.createElement("td")
                let txtPop = document.createTextNode(inputPop.value)
                tdPop.appendChild(txtPop)
    
                let tdCarac = document.createElement("td")
                let txtCarac = document.createTextNode(inputCarac.value)
                tdCarac.appendChild(txtCarac)
    
                novaLinha.appendChild(tdCEP)
                novaLinha.appendChild(tdRaio)
                novaLinha.appendChild(tdPop)
                novaLinha.appendChild(tdCarac)
            
                cTabela.appendChild(novaLinha)
    
                function limpaForm() {
                    document.getElementById('formulario').reset()
                }
                limpaForm()
            }
        insereLinha()
        }
    // S
    }
    checagemCampos()
}
    
function remover() {
    vetorPessoa = ''

    while (cTabela.hasChildNodes()) {
        cTabela.removeChild(cTabela.childNodes[0])
    }
}
```

Comment: Na verdade, eu não quero remover todos os elementos da tabela. Eu quero remover somente o elemento que for enviado pelo usuário. Por exemplo, o usuário fornece um cep para ser removido do cadastro, eu quero que esse cep seja removido da tabela que exibe o cadastro, ou seja, eu quero remover somente a linha da tabela que corresponde ao cep que deve ser removido.

Comment: Então você precisa organizar a estrutura HTML, utilizar um button específico para cada item que você quer retirar.
Especifique um pouco mais se você quer retirar o usuário ou apenas uma das 4 informações que ele cadastra.